# Unable to login, but an account exists with a different name?

Tags: virtualbox, login, password

I have the issue described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password): after a sudden stop, I can no longer log in because the computer simply flashes the login screen whenever I enter the correct password.

I followed the solution described in the top answer to that question, and rebooted. However, the issue persisted.

I noticed that on login Ubuntu is asking for `Alex`; when I reset the password using the procedure there I was told that there is no account `Alex`, but `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` revealed an account `alex`, which I did reset the password for.

On the login screen I hit `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to bring up `ttyl1`, which prompted me for username and password again. Entered `alex` and the same password as before, again, and this time it worked...I'm now logged into `alex@alex-VirtualBox`.

What's going on, exactly? How do I get back to logging in?

Comment: GUI login displays the [GECOS fullname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) whereas CLI logins use the `username` - if you do `cut -d: -f1,5 /etc/passwd` or (better IMHO) `getent passwd alex` it should clarify

Comment: `getent passwd alex` states `alex:x:1000:1000:Alex,,,:/hom/alex:/bin/bash`. The former command says a bunch more things, but the important bit seems to be `alex:Alex,,,`.

Comment: This problem persisted after I used the aforementioned procedure again to change the password to a different one. I then created a new user (as [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-quickstart)) with the same password and succeeded in logging in as that user instead. I don't suppose there's a way for my new user to "take over" my old one?

Comment: Can you log in at the CLI (e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F2) with login name `alex` and the new password you set?

Comment: Yes I can.(4char)

Comment: In that case try the remedy suggested in [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: It looks like `alex` no longer has the permissions to run any commands, `ls` included. I logged in via the `testuser` account and did some things with `sudo` to try to fix it, following the instructions on the linked thread, but to no avail, it's still stuck in a loop. Super frustrating.